# Compilation failed Internal Compiler Error: Stack too deep, try using fewer variables

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I am trying to compile the bellow contract and i am getting the error. If i remove the mapping i dont get an error:
Compiling using default compiler, solidity version: 0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang
InternalCompilerError: Stack too deep, try using fewer variables.
the contract:

```
 contract MasterContract{

struct Person
{

    uint Id;        
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string FathersName;
    string HomeAdress;        
    string PhoneNumber;      
    string Username;
    string PersonalEmail;


}

mapping(uint => Person) public person;

uint public personsCount;

function addPerson( string _FirstName, string _LastName,  string _FathersName, string _HomeAdress,  string _PhoneNumber,  string _Username, string _PersonalEmail )
 private {
    personsCount ++;
    persons_fn[patientsCount]=Patient(patientsCount, _FirstName, _LastName, _FathersName, _HomeAdress,  _PhoneNumber, _Username, _PersonalEmail);
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the error that you are having when I try to compile it. However, I had to change `persons_fn` to `person` and `patientsCount` to `personsCount` as they were not declared.

I think you just did some refactoring and forgot to change them.

Otherwise the code compiles successfully in Remix with `0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.Emscripten.clang`

Here is the fixed code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
 
contract MasterContract{

struct Person
{
    uint Id;        
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string FathersName;
    string HomeAdress;        
    string PhoneNumber;      
    string Username;
    string PersonalEmail;
}

mapping(uint => Person) public person;

uint public personsCount;

function addPerson( string _FirstName, string _LastName,  string _FathersName, string _HomeAdress,  string _PhoneNumber,  string _Username, string _PersonalEmail )
 private {
    personsCount ++;
    person[personsCount]=Person(personsCount, _FirstName, _LastName, _FathersName, _HomeAdress,  _PhoneNumber, _Username, _PersonalEmail);
}
    
    
}
```